# JS/JQ. Автоматический клик по блоку не всегда срабатывает

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть ссылка вида `site.ru/#brand=10`
При переходе на нее должен срабатывать клик по блоку с `data-id=10`. Иногда работает, но иногда не происходит клик. В чем проблема?

```
window.onload = function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace("#", "").split(";");

    if (hash[0].indexOf("brand") >= 0 && typeof hash[1] === "undefined") {
       hash = hash[0].split("=");
       var brand_id = hash[1];
       n_jQuery(".brand[data-id="+brand_id+"]").click();
       n_jQuery("html, body").animate(
           { scrollTop: n_jQuery("#sec3").offset().top },
           500
       );    
    }
};
```

Comment: Проверку на `undefined` лучше делать так:  `... === void 0`

Comment: Есть ли ошибки в консоле? Использовали ли вы `console.log()`, чтобы убедиться, что: оба ваших условия в операторе `if` правдивы, и что переменная `brand_id` содержит ожидаемое значение?

Comment: Ошибок нет в консоли. Ну скрипт же работает, только через раз. Может 3 раза сработать, а потом 1 раз - нет. Условия все выполняются. Мне кажется, что дело в том, что click не успевает сработать. Там блоки эти подгружаются ajax-ом с /api/getBrands.

Comment: Ну тогда конечно это полностью меняет картину. Если у вас есть доступ к этому аяксу, то поставьте этот код как коллбэк (функция, выполняющаяся с отсрочкой) к нему. Или используйте setTimeout, чтобы немного отсрочить выполнение кода и дать аяксу возможность загрузиться. Более точно ответить не удастся, ибо не видно этого аякса.